# Lag while fetching data from Microsoft SQL Azure from Cloud Service

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure

I have hosted my solution on azure cloud, now problem is when i try to fetch record from microsoft sql azure database from cloud service it takes too much time just to fetch few records from the table. i am using entity framework to create db instance.

This line takes too much time there are only 10 records in table

```
var modelCategories = from p in entityModel.tb_Categories select p;
```

**Function**

```
            using (iSPYDBEntities entityModel = new iSPYDBEntities())
            {
                //fetch categories from the table using entity model.
                var modelCategories = from p in entityModel.tb_Categories select p;

                foreach (var item in modelCategories)
                {
                    Categories.Add(new Category()
                    {
                        Id = item.Id,
                        Name = item.Name,
                        ImgId = Convert.ToInt16(item.ImgId)
                    });
                }
            }
```

Comment: "Too much time" is ambiguous - 100ms? An hour? Also: Are your cloud service and your database in the same region? What size role instances did you choose? What size SQL Database did you choose? Without any details, there's simply no way to know what the issue is. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: just this query takes 1 sec to fetch data .. yes both are in west europe.  subscription is as per you go.  i dont know how to check role instances ?

Comment: You said you're using cloud services (so I assumed web/worker roles). Maybe you're using a VM? Regardless, your web/worker role or VM has a size. If you chose a small size (like an A0), you'll have very low network bandwidth.  *Note: It's much better to edit your question, instead of posting more details in comments.*

Comment: VM size is small and instance is 1 for Role .. what that means ? should i increase it

Comment: Size of sql server is 250 GB, Performance level is 10 DTUs

Comment: i have increased the Size to Large but no luck still taking 12 secs to fetch data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any of the free tiers they spin down if not used for a while and it there is a delay when they spin back up.
Subsequent CRUD's after the first should be faster or use one of the paid for tiers